# Android Studio 1.2.1.1 rendering problems

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just installed Android Studio 1.2.1.1 and I'm getting this error on the main activity xml layout file:

```
java.lang.AssertionError   at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getInteger(BridgeResources.java:435)   at android.view.ViewConfiguration.<init>(ViewConfiguration.java:307)   at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:364)   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3587)   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3682)   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:493)   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:489)   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:485)   at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:103)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be something with rendering layouts using API 22. When I choose API 21 or 19 as the rendering version, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the problem. People say that it's a bug in gradle. Removing component tag from yourproject.iml files is a solution I found. It didn't work for me but hope works for you.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail or link to original source? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was because i downloaded Android Studio and automatically believed the Android SDK would be installed (Like stated on their website), however my installation provided nothing but files with a file size of 0KB in the SDK Folder. I then downloaded the Standalone SDK Tools from the same website and installed them that way... Works perfectly fine now, hope i helped :)